# async call in async void EventHandler leads to a deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, task, deadlock

Is there a way to call `SendAsync` in `OnConnect` without leading to a deadlock? I'm not using `.Wait` or `.Result` and it still leads to a deadlock.

### Edit:

The actual problem is that `SendAsync` is being called twice (once at `OnConnect` and once at `Main`). If I put a `await Task.Delay(10000)` before the second call in `Main`, it actually works good. How can I fix it? If there is no task delay, it basically hangs on `await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false)`, because it's being called twice and `async void OnConnect` is kinda "fire and forget", meaning that it's not waiting for the first SendAsync to complete, before it goes for the second call.

```cs
// Program.cs
var client = new Client(key, secret);

await client.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

await Task.Delay(3000); // This line fixes it, but it's kinda fake fix

await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
await client.SendAsync(request2).ConfigureAwait(false);

Console.ReadLine();

// Client.cs
public class Client
{
    private static long _nextId;
    private readonly WebSocketClient _webSocket;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<long, TaskCompletionSource<string>> _outstandingRequests = new();

    ...

    public event EventHandler<ConnectEventArgs>? Connected;
    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>? MessageReceived;

    public ValueTask StartAsync()
    {
        _client.Connected += OnConnect;
        _client.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;

        return _webSocket.StartAsync();  // there is a long-running `Task.Run` inside it, which keeps the web socket connection and its pipelines open.
    }

    private async void OnConnect(object? sender, ConnectEventArgs e)
    {
        await AuthAsync(...); // the problematic line
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(object? sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ... deserialization stuff

        if (_requests.TryRemove(response.Id, out var tcs))
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(message);
        }
    }

    public ValueTask<TResponse?> SendAsync<TResponse>(JsonRpcRequest request)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        _requests.TryAdd(request.Id, tcs);
        return SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync();

        async ValueTask<TResponse?> SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync()
        {
            var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
            await _client.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var response = await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false); // it hangs here (deadlock)

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResponse>(response);
        }
    }

    public ValueTask<JsonRpcResponse?> AuthAsync(JsonRpcRequest request)
    {
        return SendAsync<JsonRpcResponse>(request);
    }

    private static long NextId()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _nextId);
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class WebSocketClient
{
    private readonly AsyncManualResetEvent _sendSemaphore = new(false); // Nito.AsyncEx
    private readonly WebSocketPipe _webSocket; // SignalR Web Socket Pipe

    ...

    public event EventHandler<ConnectEventArgs>? Connected;
    public event EventHandler<DisconnectEventArgs>? Disconnected;
    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>? MessageReceived;

    public ValueTask StartAsync()
    {
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await CreatePolicy()
                    .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        await _webSocket.StartAsync(new Uri(_url), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        Connected?.Invoke(this, new ConnectEventArgs());

                        _sendSemaphore.Set();

                        await ReceiveLoopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    })
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Failed after all retries
                Disconnected?.Invoke(this, new DisconnectEventArgs(ex));
            }
        });

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async ValueTask SendAsync(string message)
    {
        await _sendSemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        await _webSocket.Transport!.Output
            .WriteAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(encoded, 0, encoded.Length), CancellationToken.None)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private IAsyncPolicy CreatePolicy()
    {
        var retryPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<WebSocketException>()
            .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(_ => ReconnectInterval,
                (exception, retryCount, calculatedWaitDuration) =>
                {
                    _sendSemaphore.Reset();

                    Reconnecting?.Invoke(this, new ReconnectingEventArgs(exception, retryCount, calculatedWaitDuration));

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                });

        return retryPolicy;
    }

    private async Task ReceiveLoopAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var result = await _webSocket.Transport!.Input.ReadAsync(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var buffer = result.Buffer;

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243427/discussion-on-question-by-nop-async-call-in-async-void-eventhandler-leads-to-a-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, those web socket wrappers are using System.IO.Pipelines, which is incorrect. System.IO.Pipelines is a stream of bytes, so it's appropriate for (non-web) sockets; a web socket is a stream of messages, so something like System.Threading.Channels would be more appropriate.

You could try something like this, which I just typed up and haven't even run:

```
public sealed class ChannelWebSocket : IDisposable
{
    private readonly WebSocket _webSocket;
    private readonly Channel<Message> _input;
    private readonly Channel<Message> _output;

    public ChannelWebSocket(WebSocket webSocket, Options options)
    {
        _webSocket = webSocket;
        _input = Channel.CreateBounded(new BoundedChannelOptions(options.InputCapacity)
        {
            FullMode = options.InputFullMode,
        }, options.InputMessageDropped);
        _output = Channel.CreateBounded(new BoundedChannelOptions(options.OutputCapacity)
        {
            FullMode = options.OutputFullMode,
        }, options.OutputMessageDropped);
    }

    public ChannelReader<Message> Input => _input.Reader;
    public ChannelWriter<Message> Output => _output.Writer;

    public void Dispose() => _webSocket.Dispose();

    public async void Start()
    {
        var inputTask = InputLoopAsync(default);
        var outputTask = OutputLoopAsync(default);

        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(inputTask, outputTask);

        if (completedTask.Exception != null)
        {
            try { await _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, statusDescription: null, default); } catch { /* ignore */ }
            try { _input.Writer.Complete(completedTask.Exception); } catch { /* ignore */ }
            try { _output.Writer.Complete(completedTask.Exception); } catch { /* ignore */ }
        }
    }

    public sealed class Message
    {
        public WebSocketMessageType MessageType { get; set; }
        public OwnedMemorySequence<byte> Payload { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    private async Task InputLoopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var payload = new OwnedMemorySequence<byte>();
            var buffer = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent();

            ValueWebSocketReceiveResult result;
            do
            {
                result = await _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.Memory, cancellationToken);
                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    _input.Writer.Complete();
                    return;
                }

                payload.Append(buffer.Slice(0, result.Count));
            } while (!result.EndOfMessage);

            await _input.Writer.WriteAsync(new Message
            {
                MessageType = result.MessageType,
                Payload = payload,
            }, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task OutputLoopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await foreach (var message in _output.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            var sequence = message.Payload.ReadOnlySequence;
            if (sequence.IsEmpty)
                continue;

            while (!sequence.IsSingleSegment)
            {
                await _webSocket.SendAsync(sequence.First, message.MessageType, endOfMessage: false, cancellationToken);
                sequence = sequence.Slice(sequence.First.Length);
            }

            await _webSocket.SendAsync(sequence.First, message.MessageType, endOfMessage: true, cancellationToken);
            message.Payload.Dispose();
        }

        await _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, statusDescription: null, cancellationToken);
    }

    public sealed class Options
    {
        public int InputCapacity { get; set; } = 16;
        public BoundedChannelFullMode InputFullMode { get; set; } = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait;
        public Action<Message>? InputMessageDropped { get; set; }

        public int OutputCapacity { get; set; } = 16;
        public BoundedChannelFullMode OutputFullMode { get; set; } = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait;
        public Action<Message>? OutputMessageDropped { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It uses this type for building a memory sequence:

```
public sealed class MemorySequence<T>
{
    private MemorySegment? _head;
    private MemorySegment? _tail;

    public MemorySequence<T> Append(ReadOnlyMemory<T> buffer)
    {
        if (_tail == null)
            _head = _tail = new MemorySegment(buffer, runningIndex: 0);
        else
            _tail = _tail.Append(buffer);
        return this;
    }

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> ReadOnlySequence => CreateReadOnlySequence(0, _tail?.Memory.Length ?? 0);

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> CreateReadOnlySequence(int firstBufferStartIndex, int lastBufferEndIndex) =>
        _tail == null ? new ReadOnlySequence<T>(Array.Empty<T>()) :
        new ReadOnlySequence<T>(_head!, firstBufferStartIndex, _tail, lastBufferEndIndex);

    private sealed class MemorySegment : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>
    {
        public MemorySegment(ReadOnlyMemory<T> memory, long runningIndex)
        {
            Memory = memory;
            RunningIndex = runningIndex;
        }

        public MemorySegment Append(ReadOnlyMemory<T> nextMemory)
        {
            var next = new MemorySegment(nextMemory, RunningIndex + Memory.Length);
            Next = next;
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

and this type for building an owned memory sequence:

```
public sealed class OwnedMemorySequence<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CollectionDisposable _disposable = new();
    private readonly MemorySequence<T> _sequence = new();

    public OwnedMemorySequence<T> Append(IMemoryOwner<T> memoryOwner)
    {
        _disposable.Add(memoryOwner);
        _sequence.Append(memoryOwner.Memory);
        return this;
    }

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> ReadOnlySequence => _sequence.ReadOnlySequence;

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> CreateReadOnlySequence(int firstBufferStartIndex, int lastBufferEndIndex) =>
        _sequence.CreateReadOnlySequence(firstBufferStartIndex, lastBufferEndIndex);

    public void Dispose() => _disposable.Dispose();
}
```

which depends on owned memory span extension methods I stole from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27869#issuecomment-475356398):

```
public static class MemoryOwnerSliceExtensions
{
    public static IMemoryOwner<T> Slice<T>(this IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start, int length)
    {
        if (start == 0 && length == owner.Memory.Length)
            return owner;
        return new SliceOwner<T>(owner, start, length);
    }

    public static IMemoryOwner<T> Slice<T>(this IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start)
    {
        if (start == 0)
            return owner;
        return new SliceOwner<T>(owner, start);
    }

    private sealed class SliceOwner<T> : IMemoryOwner<T>
    {
        private readonly IMemoryOwner<T> _owner;
        public Memory<T> Memory { get; }

        public SliceOwner(IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start, int length)
        {
            _owner = owner;
            Memory = _owner.Memory.Slice(start, length);
        }

        public SliceOwner(IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start)
        {
            _owner = owner;
            Memory = _owner.Memory[start..];
        }

        public void Dispose() => _owner.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This code is all completely untested; use at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you very much for your descriptive answer! May you add an example usage? https://pastebin.com/v6MvZDR6 here is what I did but how do I send a JSON string to the web socket endpoint?

Comment: @nop: That's a private PasteBin. To send a message, create a `Message` and write it to `Output`. To create the payload, you'll need to rent a buffer and append it to the `OwnedMemorySequence<byte>`.

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/agagetinup.csharp try this one

Comment: Give [this](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/uyozucofay.csharp) a shot.

Comment: I cannot find that `Encoding.UTF8.Convert` overload

Comment: @nop: Use .NET 6 if you haven't already. Or it's possible I mistyped something.

Comment: It is .NET 6 and it doesn't like there is such overload. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello").AsMemory()` maybe it's something like that?

Comment: Probably add a `.Span` to the first argument of `Convert`.

Comment: it doesn't work `Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder().Convert(message.AsSpan(), buffer.Memory, true, out _, out _, out _);`

Comment: You can encode to a separate buffer, then.

Comment: You could use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and then copy that buffer into the rented buffer.

Comment: It wouldn't work. I don't know. Anyway, I see there are examples that are using ArrayPool instead of MemoryPool. What's the difference assuming that I'm working on web sockets, not just sockets or so? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines there is an example using ArrayPool. You should probably make YT video tutorials about web socket client, not just TcpChat. I mean there are a lot of Tcp Chats, but none web socket client wrappers that work, you are the best in that.

Comment: I believe ArrayPool uses MemoryPool, so they're essentially the same.

Comment: I finally did it https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/xowenepave.csharp. Although something is wrong. The endpoint returns `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"bad_request","data":"invalid json","code":11050},"usIn":1649401858337963,"usOut":1649401858337983,"usDiff":20,"testnet":false}`, which means we're sending wrong payload.